# Vertically/Horizontally flip a 2d array

Tags: c, arrays

This might be considered a low-brow question. Yet, I haven't found any code, or any forums discussing how to go about this in my programming language, C. Plenty of attempt have been made, and all end up in practically "hard-coding" the new arrays.

I'm trying to vertically, then horizontally flip a 2d array.
It seemed easy enough, just went through systematically and manipulated each row and column value. But, what if I want to go about an array that isn't just a basic 3x3 array. Such as 11x11, or 15x15?

```
**CODE SNIPPET:**

int array[3][3]= { {1,2,3},
                   {4,5,6},
                   {7,8,9} };

int vertFlip[3][3],
    horzFlip[3][3]; 

for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
  for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
  {
     vertFlip[0][i]= array[2][i];
     vertFlip[1][i]= array[1][i];
     vertFlip[2][i]= array[0][i];   
  }
} //and so on for horizontal, obviously my nested for loop was different.
```

But, what if this array was something much larger, (123x123 sized array) does anyone know an effective way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Think about how to flip an array of size `N`. Once it is done, flipping a marix is almost the same.

Comment: See, I've tried to use that as an example but that's purely horizontally flipping the array. I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: Your code is using `i` as the column index, and isn't using `j` at all.

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah, like stated above, I couldn't really form a proper algorithm to accomplish this. It was mostly me hardcoding the array with the appropriate values. My point was, I wouldn't want to hardcode an array of size 123x123 haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start out with a simple approach. For horizontal flip:

```
int swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp; 
}

void FlipRow(int *row, int columns)
{
    // A row is a simple one dimensional array
    // just swap item 0 with item n-1, 1 with n-2, ...
    for (int index = 0; index < columns / 2; index++)
    {
        swap(row+index, row+columns-1-index);
    } 
}

void HFlipArray(int **array, int columns, int rows)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        FlipRow(array[row], columns);
    }
}
```

For vertical flip, use similar approach:

```
// Reuse swap
void FlipColumn(int **array, int column, int rows)
{
    // Flip column 'column' of an array that has n rows.
    for (int row = 0; row < rows/2; row++)
    {
        swap(array[row]+column, array[rows-1-row]+column);
    }
}

void VFlipArray(int **array, int columns, int rows)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
    {
        FlipColumn(array, column, rows);
    }
}
```

Note that the above code changes the contents of the input. If that is not desired, you can modify the code to pass in destination and source arrays and adjust your loops accordingly.

Comment: Within the VFlipArray function you made, FlipColumn(array,column,rows); is giving me an incompatible pointer type, indicating that (**array**) is giving my compiler errors. Why could this be? **IGNORE THIS** Fixed it, I saw the error. Thanks for the help man, I used this code as a basis and your example of the logic makes it clear what I was originally doing wrong. Will be sure to remember this.

Answer (score 1):

Hello there You can try a simple approach to `transpose` your 2d array :-

```
int ar[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int i,j,ar1[3][3];
for(i = 0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
       ar1[i][j] = ar[j][i];
    }
}
```

as you can see you just have to iterate loop to your array length and into the loop `ar1[i][j] = ar[j][i]` perform the flip operation.

Comment: you are not flipping the array, you are transposing it instead

Answer (score 0):

**Template solution**

works for arrays of `int`s, `float`s, `double`s, ...

```
template <class t>
void flip_horizontal(const int nrows, const int ncols, t* data)  // flips left-right
{
    for (int rr = 0; rr < nrows; rr++)
    {
        for (int cc = 0; cc < ncols/2; cc++)
        {
            int ccInv = ncols - 1 - cc;
            std::swap<t>(data[rr * ncols + cc], data[rr * ncols + ccInv]);
        }
    }
}

template <class t>
void flip_vertical(const int nrows, const int ncols, t* data)  // flips: bottom-up
{
    for (int cc = 0; cc < ncols; cc++)
    {
        for (int rr = 0; rr < nrows/2; rr++)
        {
            int rrInv = nrows - 1 - rr;
            std::swap<t>(data[rr * ncols + cc], data[rrInv * ncols + cc]);
        }
    }
}
```